# chrome.tabs.sendMessage : Error handling response

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im trying to send message to `content.js` from `background.js` when extension icon is clicked.

`Background.js` :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
   chrome.tabs.query({active : true, lastFocusedWindow : true}, function (tabs) {
      var CurrTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(CurrTab, 'run');
   })
})
```

`Content.js` :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(){
   view();
})
```

I have this error in `background.js`, i don't know why.

```
Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of
tabs.sendMessage(integer tabId, any message, optional object options,
optional function responseCallback): No matching signature.
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `CurrTab`? It should be a number.

Comment: Use `CurrTab.id`. See the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Background.js change the following :

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(CurrTab, 'run');
```

to

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(CurrTab.id, 'run');
```

As told by wOxxOm in the comments.

Secondly make sure that in manifest.json file you have specified the url of the website(where content script needs to be injected) in content_scripts/matches tag.